# UITableView Custom Cell Auto scroll when text field is tapped : Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Here I used Custom `UITableviewCell` and each cell having multiple `UITextfield` and it's look like as `Cardview`.

**When I click add icon new Cardview will be added.**
**Here I don't know how to handle Autoscroll option when we click on UITextfield.**

Please find below Image:

[image]

Comment: use IQKeyBoardManager

Comment: Add observer to keyboard keyboardWillShow/DidShow notification, find the size of key board from the dictionary of notification and then set the content offset of your tableView to scroll your tableView. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/making-a-uitableview-scroll-when-text-field-is-selected

Comment: https://blog.apoorvmote.com/move-uitextfield-up-when-keyboard-appears/

Answer (score 2):

No need any calculations, use below code it will work perfectly,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

 func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        reimbursementTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        reimbursementTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

API has changed a little bit with `Swift 4.2`. You need to do something similar to this.

```
//inside viewDidLoad
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

then we'll have to the supporting functions. Since we are involving selectors (which is part of Objective C stuff) we need to use `@objc` prefix with our functions.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
}
```

if you have a different name for your `UITableView` then change the variable `tableView` inside the function.

Also, if you want to hide the keyboard when the user touches outside the TextView or TextField then do the following.

```
//inside the viewDidLoad
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and implement the function given in the selector as below

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```