# How to adjust bottom constraint in the middle of "drag down" keyboard of .interactive keyboardDismissMode collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to achieve keyboard and view resizing behaviour, as shown in iOS Messages. It looks something like

https://i.imgur.com/92rvHpo.mp4

I try with the following

### Step 1

This ensures when our scroll down gesture hit the keyboard region, and keyboard will scroll down along with our gesture action.

```
collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

---

### Step 2

Adjust the bottom constraint, to ensure our collection view doesn't visually blocked by the keyboard. We adjust the bottom constraint when the keyboard finishes hiding, or keyboard finishes showing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    initKeyboardNotifications()
}

//
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808338/72437
//
func initKeyboardNotifications() {
    // If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you do not need to unregister an observer
    // that you created with this function.
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}

@objc private func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let i = sender.userInfo!
    let s: TimeInterval = (i[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    let k = (i[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
    bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = -k
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: s) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}

@objc private func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info = sender.userInfo!
    let s: TimeInterval = (info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: s) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

---

This is our imperfect outcome so far.

[image]

I guess, I need to adjust the bottom constraint real-time, when keyboard is being dragged. But, I have no idea from where I can get the keyboard height information, when it is being dragged.

Do you have any idea, how I can adjust the bottom constraint real-time, when keyboard is being dragged?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding observer for one more notification to observe keyboard height changes.

[`UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621619-keyboarddidchangeframenotificati)

Then you will get current keyboard height and can adjust your layout accordingly.

---

#### UPDATE

> Neither `keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` nor `keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` will receive notification during "drag down".

You could try adding an `inputAccessoryView` to your textField that can help you observe keyboard frame changes.

```
import UIKit

class FrameObservingInputAccessoryView: UIView {
    var onFrameChange: ((_ frame: CGRect) -> Void)?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonSetUp()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.commonSetUp()
    }
    
    private var frameObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        frameObservation?.invalidate()
        frameObservation = newSuperview?.observe(\.frame, changeHandler: { [weak self] (_, _) in
            guard let self = self, let superview = self.superview else { return }
            self.onFrameChange?(superview.frame)
        })
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
    }
    
    deinit {
        frameObservation?.invalidate()
    }
    
    private func commonSetUp() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Usage

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var onShouldBeginEditing: ((_ textField: UITextField) -> Void)?
    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        onShouldBeginEditing?(textField)
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    lazy var frameObservingView: FrameObservingInputAccessoryView = {
        let frameObservingView = FrameObservingInputAccessoryView(frame: .zero)
        frameObservingView.onFrameChange = { [weak self] (frame) in
            // update your constraint
        }
        return frameObservingView
    }()
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.onShouldBeginEditing = { [weak self] (textField) in
            textField.inputAccessoryView = self?.frameObservingView
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither `keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` nor `keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` will receive notification during "drag down".

Comment: @CheokYanCheng See the **UPDATE**.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the bottomConstraint you should instead adjust the `contentInset.bottom` of your `collectionView` when the keyboard shows/hides:

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let i = sender.userInfo!
    let s: TimeInterval = (i[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    let k = (i[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = k
    UIView.animate(withDuration: s) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}

@objc private func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info = sender.userInfo!
    let s: TimeInterval = (info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: s) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```